# Name of the proceedure used to obtain the Dirac equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-field-theory

*What follows below is a brief description of the procedure Dirac used to obtain the Dirac equation. For my question, which is about this procedure, see the last paragraph.*

Historically, Dirac was trying to find a [relativistic version of the Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Making_the_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_relativistic), just like the Klein–Gordon equation,

$$
\tag{*}\label{*}
\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} + \nabla^2\right)\phi = \frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}\phi,
$$

but which was of first order in space and time instead of second order. (This is because while the Klein–Gordon equation is Lorentz invariant and describes a particle that behaves like a particle described by the Schrödinger equation in low velocities, it is too weak in the sense that it also allows solutions with non-conserved probability currents if the normal probability density $\rho = \phi^*\phi$ is used, or alternatively, if one changes to a probability density current that is conserved, solutions with negative probability densities.)

He [proceeded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac%27s_coup) to take the square root of the wave operator (the parenthesis in the LHS of $\eqref{*}$), and assert that this was of firs order, thus:

$$
\tag{**}\label{**}
\nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} = \left(A \partial_x + B \partial_y + C \partial_z + \frac{i}{c}D \partial_t\right)\left(A \partial_x + B \partial_y + C \partial_z + \frac{i}{c}D \partial_t\right).
$$

The right hand side of this equation expands to

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle A^2 \partial_x^2 + B^2 \partial_y^2 + C^2 \partial_z^2 + \frac{-1}{c^2}D^2 \partial_t^2 \\
\displaystyle  +\, (AB+BA)\partial_x\partial_y + (AC+CA)\partial_x\partial_z + \left(A\frac{i}{c}D+\frac{i}{c}DA\right)\partial_x\partial_t + (BC+BA)\partial_y\partial_z + \left(B\frac{i}{c}D+\frac{i}{c}DB\right)\partial_y\partial_t + \left(C\frac{i}{c}D+\frac{i}{c}DC\right)\partial_z\partial_t.
\end{array}
$$

For this to match the LHS of $\eqref{**}$, we require that $A^2=B^2=C^2=D^2=1$. However, at the same time we require that $AB+BA=AC+CA=AD+DA=BC+CB=BD+DB=CD+DC=0$, which if $A,B,C,D$ are real or complex numbers is impossible, since the requirements imply that $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ must not commute. However, this is possible if $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are matrices. We already know that satisfying these requirements is possible for three matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$ (these are the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), which are three $2\times 2$ matrices). For four matrices, it turns out that these need to be of at least size $4\times 4$, for example the [gamma (or Dirac) matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) $\gamma^1$, $\gamma^2$, $\gamma^3$ and $\gamma^0$ multiplied by $i$. Hence, by taking the square root of the factor before $\phi$ on both sides of $\eqref{*}$, we get

$$
i\left(\gamma^1 \partial_x + \gamma^2 \partial_y + \gamma^3 \partial_z - \frac{1}{c}\gamma^0 \partial_t\right)\phi = \frac{mc}{\hbar}\phi,
$$

which is known as the Dirac equation. (By using the convention $c=\hbar=1$, as well as the [Feynman slash notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation), this can also be written as $\left(i\partial\!\!\!/ \ \,- m\right)\phi = 0$.) However, as we see, $\phi$ is now required to bee a vector-valued function (more specifically, $\phi: \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{C}^4$, since the gamma matrices are of size $4\times 4$, where $d=4$ is the dimensionality of the spacetime) instead of a complex-valued function, and even if $\phi$ would be vector-valued in $\eqref{*}$ as well, that equation would be weaker than the Dirac equation since it would allow solutions which the Dirac equation doesn't allow.

**My question is,** is this procedure to reduce the order of a partial differential equation known by any specific name? And has it been used in other contexts as well, except for turning the Klein–Gordon equation into the Dirac equation?

Comment: "Factorization"?

Comment: @Sal Hm, you could say that you factorize both sides of the PDE, but you also _remove_ one of those factors from each side of the PDE. Factorization alone cannot reduce the order of a PDE.

Comment: Factorization *does* reduce the order

Comment: In math, it isn't seen as a procedure that reduces the order of a PDE, as it also modifies the definition of the problem. So you get a new lower order PDE, but its solution is not a solution of the original problem. This is something that makes sense in *applications of mathematics* where, as here, it may indicate a deficiency in how you originally modelled the situation. But in math itself, what it does is find an interesting related problem, but is not directly applicable to the problem you are solving.

Comment: @Sal Then what do you mean by factorization? When I think of factorization, I think of something that turns an expression into an equivalent expression which is a product of two or more factors, and two equivalent expressions will have the same order. (This is also done here, but this type of factorization is not the only thing that is going on.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair That’s definitely true. I attempted to quantize a PDE based on the dispersion relation $\omega^2 = gk$ for deep water waves, in order to be able to simulate such waves without having to go to the frequency domain, but I found that I had to square both sides in the relation in order to be able to evaluate $k$, since I could only directly evaluate $\vec k$ which quantized becomes $-i\vec\nabla$ (and $\omega$ quantized becomes $i\partial/\partial t$), but that gave me a PDE which was of fourth order in time and unstable (is had spurious solution that exploded).

Comment: @PaulSinclair So I of course had the brilliant idea of trying to use this method to bring down the order of the PDE to something that is stable and doesn’t explode, but then I get four fields instead of just one, which I somehow need to interpret as just one field (and it’s not clear to me that the spurious solutions are gone), so now I have a new problem on my neck instead.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In case you’re wondering, the dispersion relation shows up in [Airy wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory#Solution_for_a_progressive_monochromatic_wave), if you let the water depth approach infinity.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Suppose we are seeking solutions $y(x)$ to the differential equation $Ly=0$ for a linear differential operator $L$. If $L$ may be factorized then $L=AB$ for differential operators $A$ and $B$. So we seek solutions to $ABy=0$. But then we can define $z=By$ and first deal with the lower order equation $Az=0$ for $z$. Once $z$ is known we face another lower order equation for $y$: $z=By$. If the factorization happens to be in the form $L=AA$, then we only need to deal with one related equation: $Ay=0$

Comment: @PaulSinclair I agree: the overall number of integrations is unchanged by factorization. Perhaps I should have said: "factorization reduces a higher order problem to several problems of lower order"

Comment: @Sal - actually my intent was much different, and was not in reference to your comments at all. I was just noting that the solution of the new equation does not provide a solution to the old, so from a strictly mathematical POV did not help in solving the original problem. The usefulness was in the physics, not the mathematics. But if it helped you to clarify your own point, that is all to the good.

Comment: @Sal Okay, but in our case, the original PDE isn't an equation on the form $Ly=0$, because the RHS isn't zero, so how is that applicable here?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You may move the $m^2$ to the other side, and begin with $(\square^2+m^2)\psi=0$ then the factor ansatz is $(A_\mu\partial^\mu+im)(B^\nu\partial_\nu-im)\psi\stackrel{?}{=}0$, where $A$ and $B$ necessarily are objects with indices so that the resulting 'root' is covariant. On the other hand, you have probably already factored eigenvalue equations $Ly=\lambda y$ into the form $A^\dagger A y=\lambda y$ (eg. harmonic oscillator)